# My path for soln for $~\beta~~\mathrm{s.t.} \left(u=\mathrm{powsum}(x)^{{\beta\over 2}}~~\mathrm{s. t. }~\nabla^2u=0 \right) ~$seems incorrect

Tags: derivatives, systems-of-equations

$$\text{Find}~~\beta~~\operatorname{s. t. }~\left(u(x_{1},x_{2},\ldots,x_{n})=\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}^2\right)^{{\beta\over2}}~~\operatorname{s. t. }~~\nabla^{2}u=\sum_{k=1}^{n}{\partial^2 u\over\partial x_{k}^2}=0\right)\tag{1}$$

The offical answer and my solution are different.

$$u(\boldsymbol{x})=\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}^2\right)^{{\beta\over 2}}\tag{2}$$

$${\partial u\over\partial x_{k}}={\beta\over 2}\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}^2\right)^{{\beta\over 2}-{2\over 2}}{\partial\over\partial x_{k}}\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}^2\right)\tag{3}$$

$$={\beta\over 2}\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}^2\right)^{{\beta-2\over2}}{\partial\over\partial x_{k}}\left(x_{k}^2\right)\tag{4}$$

$$={\beta\over 2}\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}^2\right)^{{\beta-2\over 2}}2 x_{k}\tag{5}$$

$$=\beta x_{k}\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}^2\right)^{{\beta-2\over2}}\tag{6}$$

$${\partial^{2}u\over\partial x_{k}^{2}}={\partial\over\partial x_{k}}\left(\beta x_{k}\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}^2\right)^{{\beta-2\over 2}}\right)\tag{7}$$

$$=\beta{\partial\over\partial x_{k}}\left(x_{k}\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}^2\right)^{{\beta-2\over 2}}\right)\tag{8}$$

$$=\beta\left\{\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}^2\right)^{{\beta-2\over 2}}+x_{k}{\beta-2\over 2}\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}^2\right)^{{\beta-4\over2}}\left(2x_{k}\right)\right\}\tag{9}$$

$$=\beta\left\{\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}^2\right)^{{\beta-2\over2}}+(\beta-2)x_{k}^2\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}^2\right)^{{\beta-4\over 2}}\right\}\tag{10}$$

Seems just$~\beta=0~$finishes the problem but the official answer says that$~\beta=2-n~$is the correct answer.

Have I made mistake(s)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\beta =0$ does indeed work because it's the trivial solution. Notice that if $\beta =0$ then $u = 1$, and clearly the derivative of $1$ is $0$.

This is kind of like when you're solving the differential equation $y' = y$, where you can clearly get $y=0$ as a solution, but since we often don't get any useful information out of this solution, it is usually discarded and we only focus on the $y = e^x$ solution.

---

Continuing where you left off we get
$$
\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x_k^2} = \beta \left( u^{1 - \frac{2}{\beta} + \color{purple}{\frac2\beta - \frac2\beta}}+ (\beta -2) x_k^2u^{1 - \frac{4}{\beta}}\right) = \beta u^{1- \frac{4}{\beta}}\left( u^{\frac2\beta} + (\beta -2)x_k^2\right)
$$
And thus
$$
\nabla^2u =\beta u^{1- \frac{4}{\beta}}\left( \sum_{k=1}^{n}u^{\frac2\beta} + (\beta -2) \underbrace{\sum_{k=1}^{n}x_k^2}_{\color{blue}{u^{\frac2\beta}}}\right) =\beta u^{1- \frac{4}{\beta}}\left(n \color{green}{u^{\frac2\beta}}  + (\beta -2) \color{green}{u^{\frac2\beta}} \right) = \beta u^{1- \frac{4}{\beta}}\color{green}{u^{\frac2\beta}}\left(n + \beta -2 \right)
$$
and if we want the last expression to be $0$, then we can take the factor $n + \beta -2 =0$ which implies $\beta = 2-n$ as desired.